# Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient Nuget package does not install Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I am building a project which involves using some calls to the TFS Extended Client Nuget package. Whenever I go to to make a call using the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` class, an error is thrown saying that the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` can't be found. I've attempted to restore all my packages, clean and rebuild, clear my Nuget cache and restore, and even a complete reinstall of VS2017 several times with no avail. The other colleague I'm working on this project with is not running into this issue. I'm currently using their DLL temporarily by copying it into the bins for all the projects in my solution as well as into the lib of my `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`. How can I ensure that the package installs the Common DLL?

Here is the specific error that gets thrown when I run a certain operation in my project:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(String name)
   at [method call] in [file name]
   at [parent method call] in [same file name]
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: Maybe this dll is installed in the GAC?

Comment: Which version did you install? And can you check if "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client" package is installed when you install "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient"? "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll" file is included in "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client".

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I just checked Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client and it is in there. I'm going through Leo's answer and fingers crossed everything goes well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient Nuget package does not install Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll

Just as Eddie said, the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` file is included in the package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client`, which is one of a dependency of package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`:

[image]

So, **to resolve this issue**, please check if the file `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` exists under the **Reference** node on the solution explorer. If it does not exist, please execute following NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project. If it was accidentally deleted or lost, restore packages, clean and rebuild, clear my Nuget cache would not modify the project to add the dll file back.